# Check BIT Column

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table:

- **Id** – unique number for every user. There will be no more than **2^63-1** users. (**Auto incremented**)
- **Username** – unique identifier of the user will be no more than 30 characters (**non Unicode**). (**Required**)
- **Password** – password will be no longer than 26 characters (**non Unicode**). (**Required**)
- **ProfilePicture** – image with size up to **900 KB**.
- **LastLoginTime**
- **IsDeleted** – shows if the user deleted his/her profile. Possible states are **true** or **false**.

This is my **SQL query**:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
Username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
[Password] VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL,
ProfilePicture VARBINARY(MAX) CHECK (DATALENGTH(ProfilePicture) <= 900000),
LastLoginTime DATETIME,
IsDeleted BIT
)
```

Is there a way to check (validate) the 'IsDeleted' column? (if it is true or false)

Comment: I think question is not clear, when you say validate with `IsDeleted`, do you mean using any procedure, function etc.. please define the complete question that address you scenario

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but... Please don't store passwords in plan text/varchar. Passwords should be hashed outside the database, and only the hash stored in the database

Answer (score 1):

Alter the column definition to NOT NULL and SQL Server will do it for you, implicitly.

A column defined as ...

```
IsDeleted BIT NOT NULL
```

... can ONLY hold the values 0 or 1, representing False or True.

A column defined as ...

```
IsDeleted BIT
```

... can *also* hold the value NULL.

However, this field should never *require* explicit "validation"!

It should not be editable by (nor even *shown to*) any User.

This is an "application" field that controls application behaviour, not a "data" field that a User can actively muck about with.

If they delete their Profile then, as far as they're concerned, it's gone.